# Setting up multiple Ubuntu servers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, puppet

I have created a project on Google Cloud Platform (also mentioned in [How do I make puppet available in Cloud Shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61181289/how-do-i-make-puppet-available-in-cloud-shell)) and wish to use Puppet in this project. A piece of advice is to follow a [tutorial on installing Puppet onto Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-puppet-4-on-ubuntu-16-04).

Unfortunately, I have never configured a server in a cloud setting before, but the tutorial requires three Ubuntu servers.

Does this correspond to spinning up three VMs in GCP, one for each server and then following the tutorial?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly what it means. You need to spin 3 VM instances.